# Minimizing data for mobile view only

Tags: css

I have a website that shows "cards" on a pinboard, 7 wide on a pc down to 4 wide on an ipad.

What I would like to happen is when the user views this on an iphone, the image with a class of "image eventItem" stays in the same location and the h4 "pinboard-day", the h4 "pinboard-date" and the p "pinboard-text" moves up on top of the image to the right and changes from black to white.

What I am trying to acheive is similar to an accordian, so that when the user clicks on the image on an iphone the standard view will appear as for pc etc.

I currently have over 150 events currently, so I am looking for a way to acheive this without having to re-write everything out again.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Milton.

```html
<div class="wrapper-pinboard">

      <nav>
          <div class="items">
              <span id="all-btn" class="item active" data-name="all" >All</span>
              <span class="item" data-name="site1" class="list">Site 1</span>
              <span class="item" data-name="site2" class="list">Site 2</span>
              <span class="item" data-name="site3" class="list">Site 3</span>
              <span class="item" data-name="site4" class="list">Site 4</span>
              <span class="item" data-name="site5" class="list">Site 5</span>
              <span class="item" data-name="site6" class="list">Site 6</span>
          </div>
      </nav>

      <div class="gallery">

          <div class="image eventItem" date="30-10-21" id="site1" data-name="site1">
              <span><img src="img/Site1-logo.jpg" alt=""></span>
              <h4 id="pinboard-day">Thursday night</h4>
              <h4 id="pinboard-date" >30th October</h4>
              <p id="pinboard-text"><b>All Welcome</b> </p>
              <br>
              <p>      $20 Entrance Fee
                  <br> Doors Open 6:00PM
                  <br> Headline act is -
                  <br> Intermission 7:30PM
                  <br>
                  <br> <b>Doors Close - 8:30PM</b> 
              </p>
              <div class="card-bottom">
                  <img id="card-bottom-site1-image" src="img/site1-139x113px.jpg" alt="">
                  <p class="card-text-bottom">
                          Premises
                      <br>Street Address
                      <br>City
                  </p>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="image eventItem" date="10-10-21" id="site2" data-name="site2">
              <span><img src="img/Site2-logo.jpg" alt=""></span>
              <h4 id="pinboard-day">Thursday night</h4>
              <h4 id="pinboard-date" >10th October</h4>
              <p id="pinboard-text"><b>All Welcome</b> </p>
              <br>
              <p>      $30 Entrance Fee
                  <br> Doors Open 7:00PM
                  <br> Headline act is -
                  <br> Intermission 8:30PM
                  <br>
                  <br> <b>Doors Close - 9:30PM</b> 
              </p>
              <div class="card-bottom">
                  <img id="card-bottom-site2-image" src="img/site2-139x113px.jpg" alt="">
                  <p class="card-text-bottom">
                          Premises
                      <br>Street Address
                      <br>City
                  </p>
              </div>
          </div>

      </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
:root {
  --light-blue: rgb(13, 110, 253);
  --dark-blue: rgb(52, 73, 94);
  --gold: rgb(255, 193, 7);
  --black-mine: rgb(33, 36, 41);
  --grey: rgb(108, 117, 125);
  --white: #ffffff;
  --black-pure: #000;
  --light-red: rgb(255, 96, 85);
}

.wrapper-pinboard {
  margin: 100px auto;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.wrapper-pinboard .items {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#year-buttons .button-years {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1600px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: space-around;
  top: 315px;
}

.items span {
  padding: 7px 7px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #34495e;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #34495e;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  min-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

#all-btn {
  width: 70px;
  text-align: center;
}

.items span.active {
  color: var(--white);
  background: var(--dark-blue);
}

.items span:hover {
  color: var(--white);
  background: var(--dark-blue);
}

#click-photo {
  color: var(--dark-blue);
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

#days-clubs-btn {
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 160px;
  left: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  border: solid .5px var(--grey);
  border-radius: 8px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#days-clubs-btn i {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 30px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.gallery .image {
  width: calc(100% / 7);
  padding: 7px;
  margin: 5px;
  height: calc(100% / 3);
  border: solid .5px var(--grey);
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  box-shadow: 6px 4px 18px;
}

.gallery #site1 {
  width: calc(100% / 7);
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  height: calc(100% / 3);
  border: solid .5px var(--grey);
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
  box-shadow: 6px 4px 18px;
  position: relative;
}

.gallery #site2 {
  width: calc(100% / 7);
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  height: calc(100% / 3);
  border: solid .5px var(--grey);
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: rgb(241, 245, 229);
  box-shadow: 6px 4px 18px;
  position: relative;
}

.gallery #site3 {
  width: calc(100% / 7);
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  height: calc(100% / 3);
  border: solid .5px var(--grey);
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
  box-shadow: 6px 4px 18px;
}

.gallery #site4 {
  width: calc(100% / 7);
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  height: calc(100% / 3);
  border: solid .5px var(--grey);
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
  box-shadow: 6px 4px 18px;
}

.gallery #site5 {
  width: calc(100% / 7);
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  height: calc(100% / 3);
  border: solid .5px var(--grey);
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: rgb(236, 237, 245);
  box-shadow: 6px 4px 18px;
}

.gallery #site6 {
  width: calc(100% / 7);
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  height: calc(100% / 3);
  border: solid .5px var(--grey);
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: rgb(236, 237, 245);
  box-shadow: 6px 4px 18px;
}

.gallery .image span {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery .image #site1 span {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery .image #site2 span {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery .image #site3 span {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery .image #site4 span {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery .image #site5 span {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery .image #site6 span {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery .image img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.gallery .image #site1 img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.gallery .image #site2 img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.gallery .image #site3 img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.gallery .image #site4 img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.gallery .image #site5 img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.gallery .image #site6 img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.gallery .image.hide {
  display: none;
}

.gallery .image.show {
  animation: animate 0.4s ease;
  width: calc(100% / 8);
  height: calc(100% / 3);
  border: solid .5px var(--grey);
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
}


/* THE DATE */

h4 {
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1rem;
}


/* THE TEXT */

p {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

#pinboard-date {
  color: var(--light-blue);
}

#pinboard-day {
  color: var(--light-red);
}

#pinboard-text {
  color: var(--black-pure);
}

.card-bottom {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

#card-bottom-site1-image {
  width: 25%;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#card-bottom-site2-image {
  width: 20%;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#card-bottom-site3-image {
  width: 40%;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#card-bottom-site4-image {
  width: 40%;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#card-bottom-site5-image {
  width: 25%;
}

#card-bottom-site6-image {
  width: 20%;
}

.card-text-bottom {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#card-bottom-apl2-image {
  width: 33%;
  height: 33%;
}
```

Comment: include your css too

Comment: css????????????

Comment: Viira, I added the CSS

Comment: Whoa - this seems to be all the CSS that you could find. Is this all really necessary to show the issue? See [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)